# How should I refer third equation that it appear as $(1)_{3}$?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}{\label{1}}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{a}_{1}& = -a_{{4}}\epsilon_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{\epsilon_{{4}}}}+a_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{
\epsilon_{{4}}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{2}& = \frac{5a_{{3}}\epsilon_{{1}}}{6}\,{{\rm e}^{\frac{3  \epsilon_{{4}}}{5}}}-\frac{3a_{{4}}
\epsilon_{{2}}}{5}\,{{\rm e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{{4}}}{5}}}+a_{{2}}{{\rm e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{{4}}}{5}}}+\frac{5a_{{4}}\epsilon_{{1}}\epsilon_{{3}}}{6}\,{{\rm e}^{\epsilon_{{4}}}}
-\frac{5a_{{1}}\epsilon_{{3}}}{6}\,{{\rm e}^{\epsilon_{{4}}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{3}& = \frac{2a_{{4}}\epsilon_{{3}}}{5}+a_{{3}}{{\rm e}^{-\frac{2\epsilon_{{4}}}{5}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{4}& = a_{4}.
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
\eqref{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [reference equation inside line with several equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338271/5764)

Comment: why are you using `eqnarray` here?

Comment: As I understand, if you need to refer to a single equation, you should break the array in single equations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Because I don't like displaying number for each equation in group of several equation. It look crowed in text. Moreover \eqnarray and \equation gives same display format for group of several equations.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You should never use `eqnarray` (for instance, it doesn't obey `fleqn`).

If you want subequation numbers in the form 1<sub>1</sub>, just do it:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\euler}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation\textsubscript{\arabic{equation}}}
\begin{align}
\tilde{a}_{1} &= -a_{4}\epsilon_{1}\euler^{\epsilon_{4}}+a_{1}\euler^{\epsilon_{4}}, \label{1-1}\\
\tilde{a}_{2} &= \frac{5a_{3}\epsilon_{1}}{6}\euler^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}
                 -\frac{3a_{4}\epsilon_{2}}{5}\euler^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}
                 +a_{2}\euler^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}
                 +\frac{5a_{4}\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\euler^{\epsilon_{4}}
                 -\frac{5a_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\euler^{\epsilon_{4}}, \label{1-2}\\
\tilde{a}_{3} &= \frac{2a_{4}\epsilon_{3}}{5}+a_{3}\euler^{-\frac{2\epsilon_{4}}{5}}, \label{1-3}\\
\tilde{a}_{4}& = a_{4}.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
References: \eqref{1}, \eqref{1-3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the input can be simplified: you have too many braces. Moreover `{\rm e}` has been deprecated more than twenty years ago and `\mathrm{e}` should be used instead. Better yet, with a macro.

If you have an older TeX distribution, you may need to use

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation$_{\arabic{equation}}$}
```

if `\textsubscript` turns out not to be defined.

Comment: Thanks for clearing difference between \eqnarray and \equation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `equation` not `eqnarray` for the first form, which gives a single reference number, if you need to reference individual lines it is more natural to use `align` than `aligned`. Also do not use `\rm` in latex (especially not in math mode). I also replaced several `{{1}}` by `{1}` as the extra groups do nothing in that case.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

either
\begin{equation}\label{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{a}_{1}& = -a_{4}\epsilon_{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}}+a_{1}{\mathrm{e}^{
\epsilon_{4}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{2}& = \frac{5a_{3}\epsilon_{1}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3  \epsilon_{4}}{5}}}-\frac{3a_{4}
\epsilon_{2}}{5}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}}+a_{2}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}}+\frac{5a_{4}\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}}
-\frac{5a_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{3}& = \frac{2a_{4}\epsilon_{3}}{5}+a_{3}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\epsilon_{4}}{5}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{4}& = a_{4}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\eqref{aligned}

or
\begin{align}
\tilde{a}_{1}& = -a_{4}\epsilon_{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}}+a_{1}{\mathrm{e}^{
\epsilon_{4}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{2}& = \frac{5a_{3}\epsilon_{1}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3  \epsilon_{4}}{5}}}-\frac{3a_{4}
\epsilon_{2}}{5}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}}+a_{2}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{3\epsilon_{4}}{5}}}+\frac{5a_{4}\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}}
-\frac{5a_{1}\epsilon_{3}}{6}\,{\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon_{4}}},\\
\tilde{a}_{3}& = \frac{2a_{4}\epsilon_{3}}{5}+a_{3}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\epsilon_{4}}{5}}},\label{align-c}\\
\tilde{a}_{4}& = a_{4}.
\end{align}
\eqref{align-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Extra braces came from Maple generated Latex code.